# Display Excel ( xls ) sheet using iframe in html

Tags: php, excel, iframe

I have an excel file in .xls format. I want to display that in my website using iFrame. 
I'm using the same iFrame code for displaying pdf file like below,

But when I try that with excel,

it's not working .

Please give me a solution if anyone knows. Thanks in advance

Comment: It's simpler to read the Excel and get your information

Answer (score 0):

Because .xls is not a web standard I don't think this is going to work. You might be better off with a table, or have you tried a gdoc?

Comment: No, the problem is that the the project is for one internal application of my company. There you cannot use google docs and all. It is fully secured and you can't even access gmail also. The datas are given in an excel sheet, in that sheet, they have some excel formulas also to calculate efficiency and some other details. So I can't save the details in a db table. I need to access details directly from excel sheet. Any idea?